# Angular 1.6 Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to learn Angular 1 for the last couple of days. It's my first foray into any MVC framework so please forgive me if this is glaringly obvious to some of you more experienced guys.

I'm following a tutorial on youtube but I've run into an error that I can't really understand.

> Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngPortfolio&p1=Erro…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A476)

I've tried googling the issue but I'm having trouble reading other peoples code and trying to relate it to my own problem (they all seem way more advanced than me).

I should mention before I continue that I followed one tutorial first that just put together everything on one page and I'm now going back on myself to try and add some sort of functioning navigation, hence why my HTML might seem a bit all over the place.

Here's what I've got so far

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body >
    <div class="container" ng-app="ngPortfolio" ng-controller="portfolioController">
      <div ng-include="'templates/nav.html'"></div>
      <div ui-view>

      </div>
      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron" ng-repeat="asset in assets">
        <img ng-src="{{asset.image}}" alt="{{asset.name}}">
        <p>{{asset.welcome}}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="well" ng-repeat="project in projects">
        <h1>{{ project.name }}</h1>
        <img ng-src="{{ project.image }}" alt="{{ project.name }}">
        <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
        <a href="{{ project.url }}">View</a>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="scripts/portfolioController.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="scripts/assetFactory.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="scripts/portfolioFactory.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

nav.html

```html
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">fabio-felizzi.com</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Change Versions <span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Angular 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Angular 4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">React</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Classic</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

app.js

```js
angular.module('ngPortfolio', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider'], function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  })
```

portfolioController.js

```js
angular
  .module('ngPortfolio')
    .controller('portfolioController', function($scope, assetFactory, portfolioFactory) {
      $scope.projects;

      portfolioFactory.getProjects().then(function(data) {
        $scope.projects = data.data;
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

      assetFactory.getAssets().then(function(data) {
        $scope.assets = data.data;
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
```

portfolioFactory.js

```js
angular
  .module('ngPortfolio')
    .factory('portfolioFactory', function($http) {

      function getProjects() {
        return $http.get('data/projectData.json');
      }
      return {
        getProjects: getProjects
      }
    });
```

assetFactory.js

```js
angular
  .module('ngPortfolio')
.factory('assetFactory', function($http) {

  function getAssets() {
    return $http.get('data/assetData.json');
  }
  return {
    getAssets: getAssets
  }
});
```

Comment: where is your controller? **portfolioController.js** this one. I have a feeling that you aren't showing the full code.

Comment: Sorry I've added that file too now.

Comment: you are missing a module obviously, the questions is which one. Have you included all the scripts that you use?
  
If you are not sure which module is missing, use the non minified angular.js which gives a readable error message.

Comment: That's a brilliant suggestion. I'll definitely do that. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to edit your question if something comes up.

Comment: Ok so now I get a bit more detail to the error:

"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string"

The only stuff I've been able to find suggests that the error is caused by a badly written array but I can't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: edit your question, add **ALL** of the code you are using and paste a link to the youtube tutorial. I think the error is wherever you are using your Factory but I really cannot see it. It'd help me a lot if you give a link.

Comment: At this point I really think you are just messing with me/us... Why did you delete the **factory** and **controller** JS snippet????

Comment: come again? I've included all the code. I promise I'm not trying to be a retard. I appreciate your help seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help. The issue was waaaaay more basic.

Here is the original app.js

```js
angular.module('ngPortfolio', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider'], function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  })
```

and here is the fixed version

```js
angular.module('ngPortfolio', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  }])
```

To save you from having to go through each character, I had to enclose EVERYTHING in .config() in square brackets rather than just $urlRouterProvider and $stateProvider. I thought the function came after the array.